# jaxb bindings add variables to generated classes

Tags: jaxb

I have a set of schemas that I generate JAXB classes from and I would like JAXB to add a new property to one of the classes for an element that doesn't exist in the schema.  How can I do this?

Comment: Are you able to achieve this? I am looking for similar jax bindings example.